# Return only one of the matching columns of a JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, r

I use RODBC to connect R to a SQL Server database, e.g.

```
test1 <- sqlQuery(channel_gh,
         query=test1.Query <- 
           paste("SELECT *",
                 "FROM Table1 a",
                 "INNER JOIN Table2 b ON a.nId = b.nId",
                 "WHERE nLeistung=",LeistungId,
                 "AND dDatum < '20150101'",
                 "AND dDatum > '20131231'"))
```

I have noticed that, in joins, columns that define the join are returned twice:

```
> names(test1)  
[1] "nId" "nLeistung" "nAnzahl"  "dDatum" "nId.1" "nQuartal" "nAGruppe" ...
```

This would be an irrelevant nuisance if it would not interfere with further work:

```
test2 <- sqlQuery(channel_gh,
                  query=test2.Query <-
                    paste("WITH Test1Restult AS (", test1.Query, ")",
                          "SELECT * FROM Test1Result tr",
                          "JOIN Table2 b ON tr.Id = b.Id",
                          "WHERE nLeistung='1144'"))

> test2
```

> [1] "42000 8156 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The column 'nId' was specified multiple times for 'Test1Restult'."
>
> [2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect [...]

If I change test1 to return only one of the Id columns, the second query works. But I do not prefer this solution because there are quite a lot of columns in Table1 and Table2 and I do not want to list all of them every time I do a join.

Unfortunately I cannot check whether this problem exists only in R-accessed SQL Server, or in general.

Is there a way to obtain only one instance of JOIN ON columns in SQL Server joins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, you would have to list the columns for all but one table:

```
SELECT a.*, b.col1, b.col2, . . . 
FROM Table1 a INNER JOIN
     Table2 b
     ON a.nId = b.nId
WHERE nLeistung = LeistungId AND dDatum < '20150101' AND
      dDatum > '20131231';
```

Other databases support the `USING` clause.  This allows you to do:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 a INNER JOIN
     Table2 b
     USING (nId)
WHERE nLeistung = LeistungId AND dDatum < '20150101' AND
      dDatum > '20131231';
```

Only one `nid` would be in the result set.  However, SQL Server does not support this (standard) syntax.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. In other words, no, there is no way round specifying all result columns for all but one database. :-(

Comment: @mzuba . . . Not easily.  You *could* use dynamic SQL, but that is probably overkill.